# Puppeteer get all <a> href links

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Hello I am trying to **scrape** a web page and return all of the links inside
example of the html element:

```
<a href="#/item/2sDSXbG">
<a href="#/item/4ssaSXbG">
<a href="#/item/Sawd432">
```

Here is my code:

```
let links = [];
let elements2 = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for (var element2 of elements2)
  links.push(element2.textContent);
```

After I return the value and print it I get an Error telling me that my variable is not defined
My Error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: links is not defined
```

End Goal:
My goal is to be able to be able to create an array of all the items in the list. I would than later parse the information so that it is just the text after /item/

Comment: Just a note: querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, which has `forEach` built in. No need for "for of`. Even if it didn't, `Array.from()` gives you `.map()`, which you almost certainly wanted here (`const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a').map(a => a.textContent)`)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your response. this returns this Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function

Comment: that's because it's missing a `)`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks again for the help. const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a').map(a => a.textContent)) is that im using

Comment: I don't see any Puppeteer code here. Can you clarify your full program context? Is this code running in `page.evaluate` or ...? Your HTML isn't valid -- most browsers would fix that, I'd think, so it's best if you can show the actual markup or URL you're scraping. `page.setContent` is useful for creating simple [mcve]s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is what you need to achieve your goal with puppeteer:

```js
const hrefs = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let links = [];
  let elements2 = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for (let element2 of elements2)
    links.push(element2.href);
  return links;
});
```

Comment: Hello this give me the following error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: element2 is not defined

Comment: @FrankFord Sorry, I've fixed the answer, please try again.

Answer (score 2):

With $$eval:

```
let hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href))
```

Answer (score -1):

The anchors doesn't have any content.
You need something like this

```
<a href="#/item/2sDSXbG">content1</a>
<a href="#/item/4ssaSXbG">content2</a>
<a href="#/item/Sawd432">content3</a>
```

Comment: This isn't my website I cannot control what it has and doesn't. I need to be able to get the href links without content